# only display one row when key field is the same

Tags: sql-server

I have created a key field (C) by joining two columns(A&C).  I want to run an sql that says, if column C is unique take only the top row.

Sample data:-

```
A                B                C                  D
10022            Blue             10022Blue          Buggy
10300            Red              10300Red           Noodle
10300            Red              10300Red           Sammy
```

so I only want one line to show for 10300Red

Cheers

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in your query.

Comment: Out of two duplicate records which record you will pick ?

Comment: @Prdp From the sample data it doesn't matter, as the rows are the same in all columns...

Comment: I would select the top one

Comment: @ZoharPeled - If am not wrong, those are not the only columns in OP's table. OP might be looking to select some other columns also

Comment: @Prdp while this is a valid assumption, I've learned that assuming things about SO questions is usually the wrong thing to do...

Comment: @Prdp, turns out you where correct after all....

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Mostly this will be the requirement but they wont add sample data or explanation properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with a cte and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A, 
           B, 
           C, 
           D, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM Table
)

SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Note:** You did say you want the "first" record, but you didn't specify the order of the records. Since tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature, "first" is simply an arbitrary row, hence "`order by (select null)`"

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
select distinct A, B, C from tablename
```

Comment: I am unable to use distinct as there are a few more other fields that exist.  sorry I didn't put that in.                                                                       Sample data:-
A                B                C                          D
10022            Blue             10022Blue      Bently
10300            Red              10300Red      Kue
10300            Red              10300Red      Warcy

Comment: You need to select the specific field you want first before you include the other

Comment: Be more specific to your question.. so that you could get a clear answer

Comment: i don't understand what you mean reds

Comment: Take a look at your question above, try to update.. Make it more clearer for you to have a clearer answer too.

Comment: it is need some field which is a  primary key field so that you can get a top row in case of duplication.

Comment: A is the primary key but picking up only one record is based on whether C is the same

Comment: It is imposible, you got two 10300 in A, Primary key couldn't be duplicated in a row.

Comment: i have joined several tables hence the duplication of the primary key.  its in a sql not a table.  never mind thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the result set by grouping it, then join it with the main table.

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    YourTable A INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            G.C,
            MAX(G.D) D
        FROM
            YourTable G
        GROUP BY
            G.C
    ) B ON A.C = B.C AND A.D = B.D
```